# Lead APEX Trigger (Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows))

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, queryexception

I want to write a trigger that creates a 6 digit code and checks if the code is unique.

First of all my trigger:

```
trigger LeadIdentCodeTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update) {  
for(Lead leadObject: Trigger.new) {    
    Boolean isUniqueIdent = true;

    // If lead cloned, check if ident is unique
    List<Lead> leadListWithSameIdent = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Ident__c=:leadObject.Ident__c AND Id!=:leadObject.Id LIMIT 1];
    if(leadListWithSameIdent.size() > 0) {
        isUniqueIdent = false;
    }

    if(leadObject.Ident__c == null || isUniqueIdent == false) {
        Boolean identExists = true;

        while(identExists == true) {
            // 1) Create new number

            identExists = false;

            // ---------------- Stringbuilder ------------------
            final String chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
            String ident = '';
            while (ident.length() < 6) {
                Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
                ident += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
            }
            // ------------------------------------------------

            // 2) Does the leadId exist?
            List<Lead> leadsWithSameIdent = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Ident__c=:ident AND Id!=:leadObject.Id LIMIT 1];
            if(leadsWithSameIdent.size() > 0) {
                identExists = true;
            }

            // 3) Yes => return Step 1, No => update lead
            if(identExists == false) {
                leadObject.Ident__c = ident;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This code runs perfectly on our test system and creates unique 6 digit code. But when I deploy the code on production I get the following error:

> LeadIdentCodeTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times) ()

I tried to mark the external id option of the Ident__c field, but it doesn't work - I get the same error.

In the past I tried to put the soql queries out of the for loop, but the same result and I saw the danger that I reach the limit of data size (because I have to get all the leads with an Ident__c value and this will be more than 200.000 leads in the future).

Now I don't have any idea to fix this problem. I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move that query out of the loop. Instead of querying each generated value separately, accumulate a set and query with an `IN` clause. Then, loop over the returned Leads and remove any duplicates from your generated ID values before populating them on your trigger set.

If your query is just an `IN` clause in your `WHERE`, filtering on an External Id field, which is indexed, that should cure your selectivity issues. You can process any Id exclusions in Apex.

That said, why not just use a native Auto Number field and save yourself the race condition that you cannot easily fix in this code? (What happens when two users insert a large number of leads at the same time?)

Comment: Thanks david for your answer! I moved the query out of the loop and build the queries with an IN clause. Now it works. Autonumber is a good idea, but that is not the right solution for us.